# change the value of input text in a form inside of form using javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, text, input

When I click on Button, I want the input text value change to 'hello', but it doesn't seem to work, here is my code. Pros please help I'm really noob, thanks in advance!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function selectfile(){
    document.uploadform.selectfile.value='hello';
}
</script>


<body>
<form name="uploadform" id="uploadform">
    <input type="text" name="selectfile" id="selectfile" value="Hi"/>
    <input name="upload_file" type="button" onClick="selectfile()" value="Button"/>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: what error are you getting? do you know about the developer console (f12 in firefox or chrome)?

Comment: I got: Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function 
O__O

Answer (score 2):

Please see this [example I put up on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/58svx/):

```
function selectfile() {
    var form = document.forms['uploadform'];
    form.elements["selectfile"].value = 'Hello';
}

var uploadButton = document.getElementById("upload-button");
uploadButton.addEventListener("click",selectfile);
```

In the handler function I first get the form by its `id` and then set the value of the element with name `selectfile` (your input element). The event listener to the button is added using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener).

**The problem in your code** is, that you called both the function and the element `selectfile`. So you are getting the "selectfile is not a function" error. Rename one of them and [it works](http://jsfiddle.net/CmyJC/).

Comment: For me the example works. You click the button and the input element's value changes to "Hello". Are you getting any errors in the console (Firebug/Developer Tools)? Which browser do you use?

Comment: Please see my edit describing what is wrong in your code. You can see it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CmyJC/). I still think however, that it's better (i.e. cleaner) to add the handler in you JavaScript code and not in your `HTML`.

Answer (score 1):

That should be working.  Is that the full HTML you're using?  If so, you need to close your tags.  It should look something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function selectfile(){
    document.uploadform.selectfile.value='hello';
    }
    </script>
</head>


<body>
    <form name="uploadform" id="uploadform">
        <input type="text" name="selectfile" id="selectfile" value="Hi"/>
        <input name="upload_file" type="button" onClick="selectfile()" value="Button"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```